# UnknownHostException while accessing www.khanacademy.org but working fine for others

Tags: java, android

I am getting UnknownHostException in Line 2 when I use url (I can access using browser): 
http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/playlists
but it works fine for all the other 2-3 url's

1. `httpGet = new HttpGet(getUrl);`
2. `response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);`

I tried searching in previous posts and tried restarting the system/emulator etc. but its not solving.

Thanks,

Comment: I have already added <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: this might be helpfull for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746375/java-httppost-into-asp-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017684/how-do-i-parse-json-from-a-twitter-search-response/7017739#7017739). The idea is the same. The String "enter" in my code will be the parsed String. Reusing tested code will save you a lot of hassle. If this doesn't help, please let me know.

Comment: It worked using your code.. I am not sure what was error in my code.. :) anyways thanks.